# Make WPF textbox as cut, copy and paste restricted

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

How can I make a WPF textbox cut, copy and paste restricted?

Comment: I dont know much about WPF. You could use a label instead (that will not let you do a cut/copy/paste.

Comment: But I want the user to input data through keyboard.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Cut, Copy, and Paste are the common commands used any application.

```
<TextBox CommandManager.PreviewExecuted="textBox_PreviewExecuted"
         ContextMenu="{x:Null}" />
```

In the above textbox code we can restrict these commands in PreviewExecuted event of CommandManager Class.

In the code behind add the code below and your job is done.

```
private void textBox_PreviewExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Copy ||
         e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Cut  || 
         e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Paste)
     {
          e.Handled = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: I think I also need to set the contextmenu to null.

Comment: Its perfect, if u disable context menu

Comment: I suggest for anyone to use it in the following form: `e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Cut`, instead of casting and relying on a string that might change due to localization. I submitted an edit suggestion to Prashant.

Comment: I am facing the same problem in my windows phone app 8.1. There is no CommandManager in windows phone application..can anyone help?

Answer (score 19):

The commandName method will not work on a System with Japanese OS as the commandName=="Paste" comparision will fail. I tried the following approach and it worked for me. Also I do not need to disable the context menu manually.

In the XaML file:

```
<PasswordBox.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste"
    CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecutePaste"></CommandBinding>
</PasswordBox.CommandBindings>
```

In the code behind:

```
private void CommandBinding_CanExecutePaste(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = false;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I used this code and it works great when you press `Ctr+V`. I noticed though that when you right click the password box, this function gets called in some sort of infinite loop. (If you add a msgbox to this function you can see that). How can that be prevented?

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBox.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut"
    PreviewExecuted="CommandBinding_PreviewExecutedCut"
    Executed="CommandBinding_ExecutedCut"/>

    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"
    PreviewExecuted="CommandBinding_PreviewExecutedCopy"
    Executed="CommandBinding_ExecutedCopy"/>

    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste"
    PreviewExecuted="CommandBinding_PreviewExecutedPaste"
    Executed="CommandBinding_ExecutedPaste"/>
</TextBox.CommandBindings>
```

In the code behind:

```
private void CommandBinding_PreviewExecutedCut(object sender, ExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
private void CommandBinding_ExecutedCut(object sender, ExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
}

private void CommandBinding_PreviewExecutedCopy(object sender, ExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
private void CommandBinding_ExecutedCopy(object sender, ExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
}

private void CommandBinding_PreviewExecutedPaste(object sender, ExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
private void CommandBinding_ExecutedPaste(object sender, ExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Panda gave me a good idea. The funny thing is the PreviewExecuted did not fire for me unless I also subscribed to Executed.
I like it better than Panda because there is no excessive looping. I like it better then Cholachagudda because his approach hid my cursor sometimes.